# display data from selected option from vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I display the data from selected option, like in the example from docs [vuejs.org](http://vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#Select) but with component?

```
<div id="app">
  <selection></selection>
  <div v-if="post">
    selected post:
    {{post.title}}
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    no posts
  </div>
</div>
```

main.js

```
Vue.component('selection', {
  template: "<select v-model='post'><option v-for='post in posts' v-bind:value='post.val'>{{post.title}}<option></select>",
  data: function() {
    return {
      posts: [{ 
        title: "lorem ipsum 1", val: '1' }, {
        title: "lorem ipsum 2", val: '2' }, {
        title: "lorem ipsum 3", val: '3' }
      ],
      post: null
    }
  },
})
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
  post: null
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cthe6qva/)

Comment: Why do you want to access selected post from parent. do it in the component itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your [component work with the v-model directive](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events) by implementing two features:

- accept a `value` prop
- emit an `input`event with the new value

First off, change your template to bind your `select` tag to the entire `post` object (not just the val property):

```
template: "<select v-model='post'><option v-for='post in posts' v-bind:value='post'>{{post.title}}<option></select>"
```

Declare your component to have a 'value' property:

```
props: ['value']
```

Now `watch` the component's `post` property and emit an `input` event with the selected post:

```
  watch: {
    post: function() {
        this.$emit('input', this.post);
    }
  }
```

Then you simply use the `v-model` directive on your custom component:

```
<selection v-model="post"></selection>
```

Here is a [complete jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/psteele/auL8ouds/) showing this in action.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for explanation.